# Weird compiler behavior when mixing Task.Run with async / await keyword

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

## Consider the following C# codes

```
var L1 =
Task.Run(() =>
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                return new Dummy();
            });
        });
    });
});

var L2 =
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    return await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        return await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            return await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                return new Dummy();
            });
        });
    });
});

var L3 =
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            return Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                return new Dummy();
            });
        });
    });
});


var r1 = L1.Result;
var r2 = L2.Result;
var r3 = L3.Result;
```

======================================================================

By first glance, L1, L2 and L3 all looks like
                  `Task<Task<Task<Task<Dummy>>>>`

Turns out, L1 and L2 are simply `Task<Dummy>`

So, I look up MSDN for [Task.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194918(v=vs.110).aspx) 

(my overloaded Task.Run is: `Task.Run<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>>)`)

MSDN says:

> Return Value is: A Task(TResult) that represents a proxy for the Task(TResult) returned by function.

It also says in the Remarks:

> The `Run<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>>)` method is used by language
>   compilers to support the async and await keywords. It is not intended
>   to be called directly from user code.

So, it looks like I should not use this overloaded Task.Run in my code, 

and if I do, compiler will strip off the extra layers of `Task<Task<Task<...<TResult>>>>` and simply give you a `Task<TResult>`

If you mouse over L1 and L2, it tells you it is `Task<Dummy>`, not my 
expected `Task<Task<Task<Task<Dummy>>>>`

So far so good, until I look at L3

L3 looks almost exactly the same as L1 and L2. The difference is:

L3 only has `async` keyword, not the `await`, unlike L1 and L2, where L1 has neither of them and L2 has both of them

Surprisingly, L3 is now considered as `Task<Task<Task<Task<Dummy>>>>`, unlike L1 and L2, where both are considered `Task<Dummy>`

My Questions:

1. 

What causes the Compiler to treat L3 differently from L1 and L2. Why simply adding `'async'` to L1 (or removing `await` from L2) causes the compiler to treat it differently ?

2. 

If you cascade more Task.Run to L1/L2/L3, Visual Studio crashes. I am using VS2013, if I cascade 5 or more layers of Task.Run, it crashes. 4 layers is the best I can get, that's why I use 4 layers as my example. Is it just me ? 
What happen to the compiler in translating Task.Run ?

Thanks

Comment: I got 7 levels deep and then VS2013 became unresponsive. It might be one of my extensions (particularly Resharper) that's to blame; I didn't go as far as checking that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What causes the Compiler to treat L3 differently from L1 and L2. Why simply adding 'async' to L1 (or removing await from L2) causes the compiler to treat it differently ?

Because `async` and `await` change the types in the lambda expressions. You can think of `async` as "adding" a `Task<>` wrapper, and `await` as "removing" a `Task<>` wrapper.

Just consider the types involved in the innermost calls. First, L1:

```
return Task.Run(() =>
{
  return new Dummy();
});
```

The type of `() => { return new Dummy(); }` is `Func<Dummy>`, and so the return type of [that overload of `Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194921(v=vs.110).aspx) is `Task<Dummy>`.

So the type of `() => ###Task<Dummy>###` is `Func<Task<Dummy>>`, which calls a [different overload of `Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194918(v=vs.110).aspx), with a return type of `Task<Dummy>`. And so on.

Now consider L2:

```
return await Task.Run(async () =>
{
  return new Dummy();
});
```

The type of `async () => { return new Dummy(); }` is `Func<Task<Dummy>>`, so the return type of [that overload of `Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194918(v=vs.110).aspx) is `Task<Dummy>`.

The type of `async () => await ###Task<Dummy>###` is `Func<Task<Dummy>>`, so it calls the [same overload of `Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194918(v=vs.110).aspx) with a result type of `Task<Dummy>`. And so on.

Finally, L3:

```
return Task.Run(async () =>
{
  return new Dummy();
});
```

The type of `async () => { return new Dummy(); }` is again `Func<Task<Dummy>>`, so the return type of [that overload of `Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194918(v=vs.110).aspx) is `Task<Dummy>`.

The type of `async () => { return ###Task<Dummy>### }` is `Func<Task<Task<Dummy>>>`. Note the nested task. So, the [same overload of `Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194918(v=vs.110).aspx) is called again, but its return type is `Task<Task<Dummy>>` this time.

Now, you just repeat for each level. The type of `async () => { return ###Task<Task<Dummy>>### }` is `Func<Task<Task<Task<Dummy>>>>`. The [same overload of `Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194918(v=vs.110).aspx) is called again, but its return type is `Task<Task<Task<Dummy>>>` this time. And so on.

> If you cascade more Task.Run to L1/L2/L3, Visual Studio crashes. I am using VS2013, if I cascade 5 or more layers of Task.Run, it crashes. 4 layers is the best I can get, that's why I use 4 layers as my example. Is it just me ? What happen to the compiler in translating Task.Run ?

Who cares? No real-world code would ever do this. There are well-known scenarios that are extremely difficult for the compiler to handle in a reasonable time frame; [using lambda expressions in method overload resolution is one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/03/28/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-five.aspx). Nested calls using lambda expressions [makes the compiler work exponentially harder](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/03/26/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-four.aspx).

Comment: Awesome answer x 2 !  I have no more fuss now, thanks